# Laravel default route for non existing route

Tags: laravel

How should I write a default route if incase the url entered does not exist? I know I can add in the Handler.php but I want it to be inside my route file.

Example.

http://valid.url.com ---> Display 1

http://valid.url.com/no-existing-route ---> Display 2

http://inactive.valid.url.com ---> Display 3

http://inactive.valid.url.com/no-existing-route ---> Display 3

http://invalid.valid.url.com/ ---> Display 4

So basically I want to catch if a url does not exist. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a catch all route and use regex matching like:

```
Route::get('{any?}', function ($any) {
    ...
})->where('any', '.*');
```

This needs to be the very last route in your list.

Comment: This solves it. Thanks a lot. Can't accept right now I'll accept once I can currently lock for accepting